# multiple event handlers in one coffeescript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, turbolinks

```
$ ->
  $("li").click ->
    console.debug "item clicked"

  $("input").change ->
    console.debug "text changed"
```

How to optimize the code to make it work efficiently with turbolinks?

Comment: Could you include the error you are receiving?

Comment: I'm sorry Canoe, but your code works perfectly: see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qvReW/)
Please give us more details about the error you're getting.

Comment: Probably an issue with other code in the file

Comment: The error is "unexpected ." which is a syntax error because the "input" wasn't quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your code seems correct, you may wish to alter it a little (for turbolinks & syntax efficiency):

```
load = ->
  $(document).on "click", "li", ->
    console.debug "item clicked"

  $(document).on "change", "input", ->
    console.debug "text changed"

$(document).ready load
$(document).on "page:load", load
```

If you're receiving an error, it's likely be cause of something else or some strange formatting issue with